# Optimizing / simplifying a path where many points are close together?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory

I have a path of points that represent the outline of a polygon. The path is constructed from pixels.

This means all points are very very close to each other, but I've ensured they are all unique.

Right now I'm checking if 3 points are collinear, and if they are, I remove the middle one.

I check if they are collinear using dot product. I observed however that many of my dot products are 0.0f. What could be wrong?

```
void ImagePolygon::computeOptimized()
{
    m_optimized = m_hull;

    m_optimized.erase(
        std::unique(m_optimized.begin(),
        m_optimized.end()),
        m_optimized.end());

    int first = 0;
    int second = 1;

    std::vector<int> removeList;

     for(int i = 2; i < m_optimized.size(); ++i)
        {
            second = i - 1;
            first = i - 2;

            if(isColinear(m_optimized[i - 2],m_optimized[i - 1],m_optimized[i]))
            {
                m_optimized.erase(m_optimized.begin() + i - 1);
            removeList.push_back(i - 1);
            }
        }

     std::sort(removeList.rbegin(),removeList.rend());
     for(int i = 0; i < removeList.size(); ++i)
     {
        m_optimized.erase(m_optimized.begin() + removeList[i]);
     }

}

bool ImagePolygon::isColinear( const b2Vec2& a, const b2Vec2& b, const b2Vec2& c ) const
{
    b2Vec2 vec1 = b2Vec2(b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y);
    vec1.Normalize();
    b2Vec2 vec2 = b2Vec2(c.x - b.x, c.y - b.y);
    vec2.Normalize();

    float dotProduct = vec1.x * vec2.x + vec1.y * vec2.y;

    //test value
    return abs(dotProduct) > 0.00001f;
}
```

The major problem is that I'm getting a lot of 0 dot products when I should not so therefore no matter where I set the threshold the path is not optimized as much as it should be.

Thanks

```
float32 Normalize()
{
    float32 length = Length();
    if (length < b2_epsilon)
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }
    float32 invLength = 1.0f / length;
    x *= invLength;
    y *= invLength;

    return length;
}
```

Comment: You say they're constructed from pixels, does that mean they're all integer coordinates? (I think I see you're storing as float, but could they be integers?)

Comment: Can you show a little bit of the code in b2Vec::Normalize() and the b2Vec2 constructor?

Comment: The coordinates are integers but I later convert them to meters hence the floats. b2vec2 is float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the 2x2 determinant `vec1.x * vec2.y - vec1.y * vec2.x` instead of the dot product. The determinant is zero iff the points are collinear, whereas the dot product is zero iff the points form a right angle.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
return abs(dotProduct) > 0.00001f;
```

is actually telling you whether your vectors are (not) perpendicular, not whether they are parallel. Check if it's close to 1 rather than close to 0 for parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You should not increment index in case the element is deleted. You are skipping some values. Try the following:

```
for(int i = 2; i < m_optimized.size();) {
    second = i - 1;
    first = i - 2;
    if (isColinear(m_optimized[i - 2],m_optimized[i - 1],m_optimized[i])) {
        m_optimized.erase(m_optimized.begin() + i - 1);
        removeList.push_back(i - 1);
    } else i++;
}
```

Also I can not understand the purpose of the `removeList`. You erase some points inside of the main loop and try to erase the same points in the subsidiary loop. It seems to be an error. BTW, there is no reason to sort `removeList` due to the way it was constructed.